# Function of a set equals the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following is given:

$x\in E \implies T(x)\in E$ and $x\in E \implies T^{-1}(x)\in E$

I'm having trouble showing that $T(E)\subset E$ or $E\subset T(E)$, let alone that $T(E)=E$. Here is my attempt:
$x\in E \implies T(x)\in T(E)$ and $x\in E\implies T(x)\in E$. But that only shows that $T(E)\cap E$ is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Given any element $a$ of $E$, your first axiom says $T(a)\in E$, so $T(E) \subset E$.  The second follows from the second axiom the same way.

Comment: How did you conclude that? I can only conclude that $T(a)$ is in $E$ (follows from axiom) and that $T(a)$ is in $T(E)$ (follows from definition of a  function), i.e. $T(a)$ belongs to both, but one statement *does not* imply the other.

Comment: $a$ is an arbitrary element of $E$, so we know $T($every element in $E) \in E$, which means $T(E) \subset E$

Comment: I'll think about that. I'm just trying to show that $x\in T(E) \implies x\in E$.

Comment: For that you need to use your second axiom, taking $T($everything)